# Android - is it possible to detect if a physical camera button is present

Tags: android, camera

I'm writing an application where I'd like to offer the user the option to remap the hardware camera button to do some other function. However if the device does not have a hardware camera button I'd like to hide this option.

Is there any way to detect the presence of the camera button on a device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think it's possible. The PackageManager class can you give you information about different things, but whether there's a hard camera button is not one of them. You can do things like:

```
boolean hasCamera = 
        getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
```

But unfortunately, there's nothing like PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_BUTTON

What you could do however is hard code in a bunch of checks for specific devices that you know to have hardware camera buttons, eg.

```
public boolean hasCameraButton() {
if(android.os.Build.MODEL.equals("droid1")) return true;
//more code here
}
```

where droid1 should be the actual id.. i dunno what it is

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to ask the user to press the camera button in order to remap it. That way only the users with the camera button will actually be able to remap it to something. The screen that asks the user to press the camera button might say "Please press your camera button. Not all devices have a camera button. If yours does not have it, press Back to cancel."